Can I use 'insertafter' to insert both xml strings and regular strings in Word VBA?
Suppose I have code that gets these two strings
    stringRegular = lineRange.Text

   stringFormatted = line2Range.WordOpenXML

The first string should be plain text.   The second string should be text that comes with its formatting (bold, italic, colors, etc).   I expected that to be true because the second string is XML that Word can interpret.
Now that I've obtained the two strings, I want to insert these two strings in a new Word document.
So I add these two lines:
        newDoc.Content.InsertAfter stringRegular
        newDoc.Content.InsertAfter stringFormatted

I find when I do this, that the first string (plain text) is inserted correctly.   The second string is inserted as if I wanted to see the underlying tags (I don't, I want to see formatted text).   An example of what I see is:
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package  ....

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Mark

You may find it helpful to look up the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertafter  Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertxml

I looked at the documentation, and the way to make an analogous function to 'insertAfter' except for XML is as follows:
Sub InsertXMLAfter(ByRef newDoc As Document, ByRef strXML As String)
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = newDoc.Content
  rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
  rng.InsertXML strXML
End Sub


Alternatively: newDoc.Content.Characters.Last.InsertXML strXML
